# Django: Getting last value by date from related model in admin. Best way?

Tags: django, django-admin

Say I have a model like

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    [...]
```

and another like

```
class Price(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')
    date = models.DateField()
    value = models.FloatField()
    [...]
```

and I want to display products in a modelAdmin, with the last price registered in a column.

So far, the only way I have found is to add the following method to the product object:

```
@property
def last_price(self):
    price = Price.objects.filter(product=self.pk).order_by("-date")
    return price[0].value if price else None
```

and then adding last_price to the list_display in Product's ModelAdmin. I don't like this approach because it ends up doing a query for each row displayed.

Is there a better way to do this in code?. Or do I have to create a column in the Product table and cache the last price there?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner version of what you have would be:

```
def last_price(self):
    latest_price = self.price_set.latest('date')
    return latest_price.value if latest_price else None
```

But this still involves queries for each item.

You if you want to avoid this I would suggest adding a `latest_price` column to `Product`.  Then you could set up a `post_save` signal for `Price` that then updates the related `Product` `latest_price` (This could be a ForiegnKey or the value itself.)

**Update**

Here is a receiver that would update the products latest price value when you save a `Price`.  Obviously this assumes that you are saving `Price` models in chronological order so the lastest one saved is the latest_value

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Price)
def update_product_latest_value(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.product.latest_value = instance.value
        instance.product.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks a lot better (didn't know about the latest function), but it confirms my fears that I need to cache the column. If no one says otherwise, I'll mark your answer as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you earlier, Easter holidays and all that. I will indeed have to cache that column, thanks for the extra code!

Answer (score 2):

to reduce the the queries for each entry use the following:

```
Price.objects.filter(product=self.pk).order_by("-date").select_related('product')
```

this will decrease the product query at each object, hope it is helpful, vote up please

Comment: I'm afraid not. If I was in a view and I was doing some kind of Product.objects.all.filter(whatever).order_by("-date")[:20], then Product.objects.all.filter(whatever).order_by("-date").select_related('price').annotate.etc would indeed help. As it is, debug_toolbar confirms that a single query is still being done for each row in the table. Still, thank you for trying!.